# scala comparator like function for sequences

Tags: scala, comparator, seq

Given I have two `Seq[M]` and a comparator like function `compare(m1:M, m2:M):Int`, how would I write the comparator like function for the two sequences.

```
def compare[M](s1:Seq[M], s2:Seq[M], cmp:(M,M)=>Int) : Int = {
  ???
}
```

I would have no problem to implement this myself iterating over the sequences, but I am sure there is something ready made in the Scala library already. I look at the `Ordering` class and object but have problems to see the forest for all of the implicit trees.

EDIT: Any way to make use of `seqDerivedOrdering` that can be seen in
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L1 other than copying the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `seqDerivedOrdering` but you still have to provide an implicit ordering as it doesn't take `(M,M) => Int`. You could try something like this:

```
  def compare[M](s1: Seq[M], s2: Seq[M])(cmp: (M, M) => Int): Int = {

    implicit val orderM = new Ordering[M] {
      override def compare(x: M, y: M): Int = cmp(x, y)
    }

    scala.math.Ordering.Implicits.seqDerivedOrdering[Seq, M].compare(s1, s2)
  }
```

And perhaps a slightly better version of the same code:

```
  def compare[M](s1: Seq[M], s2: Seq[M])(cmp: (M, M) => Int): Int = {

    import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

    implicit val orderM = new Ordering[M] {
      override def compare(x: M, y: M): Int = cmp(x, y)
    }

    implicitly[Ordering[Seq[M]]].compare(s1, s2)
  }
```

Or, we can do even better:

```
  import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

  def compare[M](s1: Seq[M], s2: Seq[M])(cmp: (M, M) => Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[Seq[M]]): Int = {

    implicit val orderM = new Ordering[M] {
      override def compare(x: M, y: M): Int = cmp(x, y)
    }

    ord.compare(s1, s2)
  }
```

Comment: After reading http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html, the last one started to make sense to me. Alas the orderM does not seem to be necessary anymore. At least it works for List[Int] and List[String] without.-) And then it is really nice and simple.

Comment: Uuhm, oh, now I got it. Without the orderM, my cmp is never used.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything built in as far as I know.  The most compact is probably something like

```
def compare[M](s1: Seq[M], s2: Seq[M], cmp: (M, M) => Int): Int = {
  val diff = (s1 zip s2).find(x => cmp(x._1, x._2) != 0)
  diff.map(x => cmp(x._1, x._2)).getOrElse(s1.length compare s2.length)
}
```

The solution with iterators is more efficient but less compact.